# The value is not updating dynamically until refresh button is clicked-Spring+Angular

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

It's Spring+Angular CURD app. Problem is whenever a user enters the details and hit submit button the records are successfully getting inserted into dB tables but the view is not updating with an extra row(new data) until the refresh button is clicked.
After refreshing the page it's successfully showing all the records.
But it should show the data dynamically

And it works fine for delete option whenever delete button is clicked it's deleting a row from view page(table) and db Table too.

MyController
-----------------

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/home")
    public ModelAndView getHomePage() {
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addUser(@RequestBody UserCommand user){
        int result= 0;
        UserDto dto= null;
        dto= new UserDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, dto);
        result= service.processUser(dto);
        if(result!=0) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/userDetails",produces="application/json",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<UserDto> getAllUsers(){
        List<UserDto> listDto= null;
        listDto= service.retrieveAllUsers();
        return listDto;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/deleteUser",method=RequestMethod.DELETE,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAUser(@RequestBody UserCommand cmd){
        int result= 0;
        result= service.deleteUser(cmd.getEmail());
        if(result!=0) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

Home.jsp

------------

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home | Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/main.css"></c:url>'/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app= angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("HomeController",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.users=[];
        $scope.userform={
            name: "",
            email: "",
            mobile: ""
        };

        getUserDetails();

        function getUserDetails(){                      //this method
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'userDetails',
            }).then(function successCallback(response){
                $scope.users= response.data;
            },function errorCallback(response){
                alert(response.statusText);
            });
        }

        $scope.addUser= function(){                   //Problem Lies Here
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'add',
                data: angular.toJson($scope.userform),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(getUserDetails(),clearForm());   //it's calling above function to get the updated data
        }                                           //------------------------------------

        function clearForm(){
            $scope.userform.name="";
            $scope.userform.email="";
            $scope.userform.mobile="";
            document.getElementById("name").disabled= false;
        }

        $scope.deleteUser= function(user){
            $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: 'deleteUser',
                data: angular.toJson(user),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(getUserDetails());
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <h1>Spring+Angular CURD Application</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="500px">
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" ng-model="userform.name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" ng-model="userform.email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="mobile" ng-model="userform.mobile"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200px">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" ng-click="addUser()" value="Add"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>
    </form>

    <h2>Registered User's</h2>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="600px">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Operation's</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.mobile}}</td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="deleteUser(user)">Delete</button> | 
                <button ng-click="editUser(user)">Edit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing function `then` callback as:

```
$scope.addUser = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'add',
        data: angular.toJson($scope.userform),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        getUserDetails();
        clearForm());
    })
}
```

As you use it in function `getUserDetails()`.